# The type or namespace name 'SerializableAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, xsd, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro

When generating c# code for an xml file using xsd I am getting the error:

The type or namespace name 'SerializableAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'DesignerCategoryAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

the generated code that gives the error:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
```

I tried searching for an answer. The only thing I found is this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/916649

That does not work for me though. there is no system folder in solution explorer! I am using visual studio 2012 and I am developing a c#/xaml metro app!

Comment: Do you have a namespace in your application that's called `System`? If you have, for example, `using MyApplication.System` somewhere, then `System` will resolve to your System namespace rather than to the mscorlib System namespace.

Comment: I have searched the entire solution and there is no namespace called System! I am using a listView template! The xml, xsd and the generated c# files are the only code I have added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay looks like xsd is not yet supported with metro applications! The following link explains that!

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/88d9b73b-5faa-4204-9d06-dc121e709943/

the Perl script in the last answer can be used to remove the [System.SerializableAttribute()] and [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")] annotations if you have a big deep xml structure! I did not so I just removed them manually!

I am not sure if removing these annotations will have any bad side effects though. I will update this answer if I face any!

Thanks